# date_default_timezone_set displays incorrect time

Tags: php, timezone

I'm using date_default_timezone_set function to set the timezone but when I echo the time it displays wrong time on local server xampp

```
date_default_timezone_set ('Africa/Cairo');
echo "<div style='direction:ltr'>".date("Y-m-d / g:i A")."</div>";
```

the time now is 10:50 am but it displays 9:50 am. So any ideas?

Comment: Is the system's clock set correctly? Check if UTC time is correct. Is your PHP version and/or your timezone database up to date?

Comment: Maybe the server's time is set incorrectly, or it doesn't have correct configuration file for daylight savings time.

Comment: No it's correct and daylight savings time will start tomorrow and when it changes an hour will be add so 10 will be 11 and there'll be 2 hours difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible issues:

- the server's time is not set correctly, test this by confirming that time in the UTC timezone is correct
- the timezonedb is outdated and the timezone in question has changed its DST rules in the meantime, update your PHP version and/or your [timezonedb via PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb)

Comment: You checked the other things mentioned? I agree on his opinion.

Comment: @jqb Any idea when Cairo introduced and/or changed its DST rules?